# Firebase AppCheck for Flutter Windows

Tags: windows, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-storage, firebase-app-check

Is there a way to use Firebase App Check for Flutter Windows app?
We can use Firedart module to set up the Firestore for Flutter Windows App, but can we also use Firebase AppCheck?

I tried using "firebase_app_check" plugin but I do not think it works?